# How to call a ontap fuction in another widget indirectly in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-widget, flutter-onpressed

I'm using animated container for getting toggle button like in android. Here my code is working for toggle button function perfectly. But what i need is, if i press some other button, toggle button should function. see the below image for your reference(if i press "Press" button it should operate toogle button). Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJpWT.jpg

```
class DialogExample extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _DialogExampleState createState() => new _DialogExampleState();
}

class _DialogExampleState extends State<DialogExample> {

  bool toggleValue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:180.0),
            child: Center(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: toggleButton,
                child: AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                  height: 40.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    color: toggleValue ? Colors.deepOrangeAccent : Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  ),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      AnimatedPositioned(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                        curve: Curves.easeIn,
                        left: toggleValue? 60.0 : 0.0,
                        right: toggleValue ? 0.0 : 60.0,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: toggleButton,
                          child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                            child: toggleValue ? Icon(Icons.check_circle,color: Colors.white,size: 39.0, key: UniqueKey(),)
                                : Icon(Icons.check_circle,color: Colors.white,size: 39.0,
                              key: UniqueKey(),),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:80.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("press"),
              onPressed: (){
                toggleButton;
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  toggleButton() {
    setState(() {
      toggleValue = !toggleValue;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your button code with the below code block. Actually you are calling toggle button inside a method, So, it is unable to  recognition it.

```
Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:80.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("press"),
              onPressed:toggleButton,
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace toggleButton with, because that is not valid statement here.

```
toggleButton();
```